# Dynamics API Contact creation error with UUID reference properties

Tags: postman, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Dynamics CRM instance that I am initially successfully accessing via Postman.
This is v9.0

I have a POST request which creates a new contact at: /api/data/v9.0/contacts

```
{
    "customertypecode": 127840004,
    "xx_contractorstatus": 127840000,
    "firstname": "Wallie",
    "lastname": "Worker1-7",
    "fullname": "Wallie Worker",
    "emailaddress1": "wworker1@test.com"
}
```

I also have a custom list of nationalities at: /api/data/v9.0/xx_nationalities
The structure of xx_nationalities is:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://xxdev.api.[HIDDEN].dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#xx_nationalities",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"35347625\"",
            "_organizationid_value": "6b47908f-b289-4601-b80c-59667d32deda",
            "xx_sharecoderequired": true,
            "xx_nationalityid": "297db2c4-15a3-ed11-aad1-0022484257f7",
            "xx_name": "Afghan",
            "xx_wrsregistrationrequired": false,
            "xx_visarequired": true,
            "statuscode": 1,
            "importsequencenumber": 20,
            "_createdby_value": "2c738c48-4115-ec11-b6e6-002248412237",
            "modifiedon": "2023-02-02T16:22:38Z",
            "xx_brprequired": true,
            "_modifiedby_value": "2c738c48-4115-ec11-b6e6-002248412237",
            "versionnumber": 35347625,
            "createdon": "2023-02-02T16:22:38Z",
            "statecode": 0,
            "overriddencreatedon": null,
            "_modifiedonbehalfby_value": null,
            "xx_nationalityfullname": null,
            "utcconversiontimezonecode": null,
            "_createdonbehalfby_value": null,
            "xx_iseu": null,
            "timezoneruleversionnumber": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to attach a nationality to the contact upon Contact creation but am getting errors. When xx_nationality is returned within a Contact GET it is named as:
`"_xx_nationality_value": "5f7db2c4-15a3-ed11-aad1-0022484257f7"`

I have tried direct to returned value, with id, using @odata.bind, with entity wrapping and with. / without slash in value and underscore in property. But nothing seems to work.

`"_xx_nationality_value": "5f7db2c4-15a3-ed11-aad1-0022484257f7"`

error: CRM do not support direct update of Entity Reference properties, Use Navigation properties instead

`"_xx_nationality_value@odata.bind": "/xx_nationalities(5f7db2c4-15a3-ed11-aad1-0022484257f7)"`

`"xx_nationalityid@odata.bind": "/xx_nationalities(5f7db2c4-15a3-ed11-aad1-0022484257f7)"`

`"xx_nationalityid_nationalities@odata.bind": "xx_nationalities(5f7db2c4-15a3-ed11-aad1-0022484257f7)"`

`"xx_nationalityid_nationalities@odata.bind": "/xx_nationalities(5f7db2c4-15a3-ed11-aad1-0022484257f7)"`

error: Microsoft.OData.ODataException: An undeclared property '_xx_nationalityid_nationalities' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload

This seems to be something which is possible and probably very obvious but this is our first excursion into hitting the CRM and we can't find a solution within the docs and unfortunately we can't download the /api/data/v9.0/$metadata file as its too large to browser or Postman.

Comment: use my tool Dataverse REST Builder to create the request https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB

Answer (score 0):

can't you use XrmToolBox with MetadataBrowser plugin to get metadata only of your entity?
Then you should be able to check the right property name.

Answer (score 0):

Its not 100% clear from you post what you data structure looks like.  But from reading it it looks like there is a many-to-many relationship between contact and nationalities.

You need to use an "Associate" request to create the intersect record.  Under the hood D365 / CRM creates an internal table to handle this relationship.

The page on the Associate Request of the WEB API SDK is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/associate-disassociate-entities-using-web-api

But the association request will look something like this:

```
POST [Organization Uri]/api/data/v9.2/xx_nationalities(ce9eaaef-f718-ed11-b83e-00224837179f)/xx_contact_nationality_relationshipname/$ref HTTP/1.1
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
If-None-Match: null
Accept: application/json

{
  "@odata.id": "[Organization URI]/api/data/v9.2/contacts(cf9eaaef-f718-ed11-b83e-00224837179f)"
}
```

You will need to specify the correct relationship above for yourself.  Easiest thing to do is install the CRM REST Builder solution on your dev environment to quickly build the correct query.

The relationship name (schemaname) can easily be read from: Default Solution->Contacts->N:M Relationships